# Can You Identify This Grass?

Tags: grass, fescue

Can anyone identify this grass or weed that has sprouted up in my healthy fescure? Please see picture. I have a pretty good tall fescue lawn that I have been working on getting out the crabgrass and various weeds with "0.28% Barricade pre-emergent Weed-Feed fertilizer applied in late March and a good post-emergent spot-spray weed killer this spring. So far, so good. The fescue yard really looks great.  BUT...I have a new patch of this unidentified grass or weed with seeds at the top that just popped up a week or two ago as shown in the picture. It's in an area 20x20 feet only...and it was an area that got a good strong dose of the weed and feed in March. The unidentified interloper is a bit lighter shade of yellow-green (at the top of the picture) than healthy dark green fescue (at the bottom of the picture). And it has what appears to be seeds at the top. I live in zone 7. Thank you. Mark [image]

Answer (score 3):

I'm not very good on grasses, but it looks like Poa Annua.  A variety of grass contained in a standard mix of grass varieties for use in uk lawns.

Comment: Rosie, I think you are correct. The pictures I saw on Google for Poa Annua look almost identical. Thanks so much!

Comment: Yep looks like Pa Annua. People actually intentionally put them in seed mixes? :( It's usually considered a weed. Hard to kill because it's a grass and there may only be one selective herbicide for it. You usually have to kill the whole thing and start over. Spreads pretty fast.